# MySQL CE - Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server with VSCode

Tags: windows-10, mysql, visual-studio-code

I am trying to connect Visual Studio Code to a database.

I created a database on MySQL server(Community edition) but I am encountering the following error:

> MySQL Error: Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

the solution to this problem can be solved by running either of the two code options on MySQL Community as a query. from a realization, MySQL 8.0 uses a new default authentication plugin - **caching_sha2_password** 
- whereas MySQL 5.7 used a different one - **mysql_native_password. Currently**, the community visual studio code for MySQL don't support compatible client-side authentication mechanisms for the new server plugin.

A possible workaround is to alter the type of user account to use the old authentication plugin:

**ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'MyNewPass';**

Or create a different one that uses that same plugin:

**CREATE USER 'foo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'bar';**